# Python 3 dynamic inheritance with metaclasses and abstract classes

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class, metaclass

I'm trying to dynamically inherit from a class `MyMixin` with metaclasses. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python/6581949#6581949) excelent answer and [this](https://gist.github.com/niwinz/3654502) code snippet, I got this working:

```
class DynamicInheritance(type):
    """
    Dinamicaly modify class with some extra mixin.
    """
    def __call__(cls, mixin, *args, **kwargs):
        new_cls = type(cls.__name__, (mixin, cls), dict(cls.__dict__))
        return super(DynamicInheritance, new_cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

class MyMixin:
    def bye(self):
        print("bye")

class Foo(metaclass=DynamicInheritance):
    def hello(self):
        print("hello")

foo_instance = Foo(MyMixin)
foo_instance.hello()
foo_instance.bye()
```

Output:

```
hello
bye
```

However, when `Foo` inherits from an abstract class, things stop working:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class FooAbstract(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def hello(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def bye(self):
        pass

class Foo(FooAbstract, metaclass=DynamicInheritance):
    def hello(self):
        print("hello")

foo_instance = Foo(MyMixin)
```

Output:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Can someone explain what the problem is?

Comment: If I understand correctly, calling `Foo` both creates a new subclass of `Foo` on the fly *and* instantiates it. I wouldn't try to combine those two. What's wrong with `foo_instance = type('...', (Foo, MyMixin), {})()` instead, dispensing with the metaclass altogether? (Assuming there's a reason to create such one-time-only classes in the first place.  Given `f1 = Foo(MyMixin)` and `f2 = Foo(MyMixin)`, `f1` and `f2` do *not* have the same type.)

Comment: I tried to simplify my example as much as possible. In the real use case, there are two "MyMixin1" and "MyMixin2" and we want to inherit from one or another base on some condition.

Comment: The problem is that metaclasses do not easily compose. `ABCMeta` and `DynamicInheritance` are both subclasses of `type`, but neither is a subclass of the other. Python will not even let you *try* to mix the two together unless you can demonstrate via subclassing that one is a kind of the other.

Comment: By "combine", I mean defining some class like `class DIABC(ABCMeta, DynamicInheritance): ...` that explicitly spells out how to make use of both in a sensible way.

Comment: Closing as a duplicate. This question arises with certain frequency, and there are better answers if you search for "metaclass conflict".. I just happened to link to one I answered last week or so.

Comment: It is actually very difficult to arrive to your answer (which is great) when searching for this type of problem.